# Open street map data - electoral wards

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, openstreetmap

Im struggling to find the correct key and value to plot electoral wards in R's `osmdata`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(osmdata)

ward <- getbb("Sheffield United Kingdom") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature(boundary="political", political_division="ward") %>%
 osmdata_sf()
```

`key` is specified as an input typically of the nature "highway" and value would in such case be `motorway` but the docs don't clarify what can be used in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with passing the `key` and `value` to `add_osm_feature()` function

```r
library(osmdata)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

ward <- getbb("Sheffield United Kingdom") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value ="political") %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "political_division", value ="ward") %>%
  osmdata_sf() 

sheffield <- getbb("Sheffield United Kingdom") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value ="administrative") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

d8 <- st_as_sf(sheffield$osm_multipolygons) |>
  filter(admin_level == 8 & name == "Sheffield") |>
  select(osm_id, name, geometry)

plot(d8$geometry, col = "gray")
```

The objects returned with osmdata are long lists, consisting of `osm_points`, `osm_lines`, `osm_polygons` (created from closed lines) and `osm_multipolygons` (created from osm relations), therefore we can suspect wards in `osm_polygon` and `osm_multipolygon`. You can `st_cast()` multipolygons to polygons and then merge both features.

```
plot(st_as_sf(ward$osm_multipolygons$geometry), add=TRUE, col = "yellow")
plot(st_as_sf(ward$osm_polygons$geometry), add=TRUE, col = "lightyellow")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>